# tput command + bold specific strings in file

Tags: solaris, shell-scripting, terminfo, command-line-interface

please advice how to bold the "Date & Time" numbers from the following file with tput command ( I have Solaris machine)

for example I want to bold only the "24-09-2009 16:17:45" etc for all other date and time

the tput will write in my ksh script

thx for the support

```
  TIMESTAMP               SET_ID TELEPHONE                    No TYPE
  ------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ------------------

  24-09-2009 16:17:45          0 33633333333                  20 other_mms_phone
  24-09-2009 17:45:07          0 33644444444                  20 other_mms_phone
  07-10-2009 10:45:49          0 12312312312                  20 legacyphone
  07-10-2009 11:46:38          0 59320000043                  20 other_mms_phone
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the fine terminfo(5) manual, it lists all terminal capabilities.  Depending on the terminal, 'bold' capability might not be defined, use 'smso' then.

```
bold=`tput bold`; sgr0=`tput sgr0`
echo to ${bold}boldly${sgr0} go somewhere
```